# Spring Boot REST API - Deserialise a query attribute with square braces with Jackson

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc, jackson

i am calling a legacy rest endpoint. There i have to deserialise a query parameter in a rest endpoint with square braces *author[name]*.

*Question*: Is it possible to deserialise the attribute *author name* into the AuthorDto(spring boot + kotlin)?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController


@RestController
class AuthorController {


    @GetMapping("/author/{id}")
    fun getAuthorFromLegacyApi(
        @PathVariable("id") id: Long,
        authorDto: AuthorDto?
    ) = ResponseEntity.ok(authorDto)

}

@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
data class AuthorDto(
    @RequestParam(name = "author[name]")
    val name: String?,
    // long list of different query parameters
    val country: String? = null,
)
```

- code: https://github.com/nusmanov/spring-boot-validation-hibernate/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/com/example/bookvalidation/author/AuthorController.kt
- to test: GET http://localhost:8080/author/5?author[name]=Joe
- there is a junit test see above

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, if you annotate `authorDto` with `@RequestParam("author[name]")`:

```
@GetMapping("/author/{id}")
fun getAuthorFromLegacyApi(@PathVariable("id") id: Long, @RequestParam("author[name]") authorDto: AuthorDto) = ResponseEntity.ok(authorDto.name)
```

Comment: hi Ervin,

the AuthorDto has more than one attribute, sorry i added in the code also.
Adding the RequestParam did not help.

data class AuthorDto(@RequestParam("author[name]") val name: String?, val country: String? = null)

Answer (score 0):

How about using the map.

```
    @GetMapping("/author/{id}")
    fun getAuthorFromLegacyApi(@PathVariable("id") id: Long, @RequestParam authorDto: Map<String, String>): String {
        return "Hello $id ${authorDto["author[name]"]} ${authorDto["currency"]}"
    }
```

I tried with `author/5?author%5Bname%5D=Tom&currency=INR` got the response of `Hello 5 Tom INR`